# I see these types of plots a lot in older publications. What software/method is used to make this plot?

Tags: publications, physics, graphics, science, chemistry

Anyone know what software or method is used to make these classic black and white publication figures with all caps axis labels and typically a gridded background?
Just curious because I have seen them across fields.

[image]

taken from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B0122274105002921

Comment: Once upon a time, companies and universities had graphic artists on staff to make such plots.

Comment: Just a starter
https://scipython.com/blog/old-style-matplotlib-charts/
(do you want to impress negatively the scientist? use as your only font  comic sans and plot everything in xkcd style ;) )